# SignalR: how to wait for connection

Tags: javascript, signalr, signalr.client

I'm using next code snippet to create a SignalR Hub Connection:

```
const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/huburl")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

async function start() {
    try {
        await connection.start();
        console.log("SignalR Connected.");
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(start, 5000);
    }
};

// Start the connection.
start();
```

And after this script, I do some AJAX call to display information on my webpage. In that AJAX call are several status messages I want to receive with my Hub, but I always miss the first x messages.

Some debugging let's me think the connection to my Hub is not yet completed (state is not 'connected') when the first messages are sent by the server.

How can I wait for the Hub to be connected before I do the AJAX call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I found something that worked for me:

Added a boolean 'connected' to the given script:

```
let connected = false;

const connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl("/huburl")
    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
    .build();

async function start() {
    try {
        await connection.start();
        console.log("SignalR Connected.");
        connected = true;
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        setTimeout(start, 5000);
    }
};

// Start the connection.
start();
```

Then created an async method that checks the boolean every 200ms:

```
async function WaitForHubConnection() {
    while (true) {
        if (connected) {
            console.log("Connection verified");
            return;
        }
        else {
            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 200));
        }
    }
}
```

And finally I need to await the WaitForHubConnection(), but did not know the jQuery document ready method could be asynchronous, but it works:

```
$(document).ready(async function () {
    await WaitForHubConnection();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/ajaxUrl',
        type: 'get',
        data: {  },
        beforeSend: function() { },
        headers: { },
        success: function(data) { }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why not just `await connection.start();`?